# How can i find a invalid timestamp record in a table of million records in teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have a table in which millions of records are there. In one of the records, there is column with datatype as `timestamp(0)`.
There is a invalid timestamp data in that column. 
How can I get that record?

Please help me?

Database I am using is Teradata.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by invalid timestamp? If the column datatype is timestamp(0), it won't allow invalid timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is a Varchar column which you are trying to cast into a timestamp. You generally want to match a pattern in the string to see if it matches the valid timestamp format. You can define the pattern using a regular expression and use `regex_similar()` UDF in Teradata to identify records which match the pattern. A sample regex for `timestamp(0) format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'` is `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`

Note: You may need to ask the support teams/DBAs to install this UDF for you. I would recommend that you install this UDF anyway because of the its extremely versatile usage.